# Regex to find sentences containing a certain word and consider floating point numbers as part of sentence

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am searching a regex that can find a certain word in a sentence. However, the sentences in my case often contain (floating point) numbers. Common solutions for finding a word don't consider special types of numbers in them. (At least not those I found)
I have created one that does the job in my test case but has problems in other cases with catastrophic backtracking. In my regex I want to prevent catastrophic backtracking, but this exceeds my regex knowledge.

Here one of the versions of my regex: `(\d+([.,]?\d+)*|[\w\s\(\[\{])*?(?<=[.?!;\s({[])\b[sS]cope\b[\s\S]*?(?<!\d)[.?!;](?!\d)`

I know that there are other solutions out there, one being sentence tokenisation with nltk. That's the solution I used then. I ask this question out of interest and am only interested in regex solutions.

All example texts are from some random PDFs of the internet, hence the strange looking sentences.
Here one example where it works perfectly: https://regex101.com/r/12Xo8k/1
Here one example where it doesn't work and where the searched word is not contained: https://regex101.com/r/RvBYhL/1

Comment: Have you read the error message on the right? *"Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your expression has been halted. To find out more and what this is, please read the following article: [Runaway Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)"*. Please check that link.

Comment: About your second example string: convert it to utf-8 first. Also add a tag to your question with the language you use or at least the regex engine.

Comment: Yes, I have read this article, However, as my knowledge on regex is not that big, I couldn't figure out on how to use it on mine. My regex might give the impression that I knew what I was doing, but it was rather a trial and error and putting stuff together, that works on its own.